# Capturing preceding tag reference instead of actual tag reference

Tags: regex

I have hit a brick wall trying to select text based on custom tags we have created.

I want to select the following **BOLD** tag:

> *[AREA ROW, CHNO]Your card will be charged in Euros.[/AREA]* **[AREA UK,
>   US, HK]Discover,[/AREA]**

But using the following regex:

```
\[AREA\s((.*),\sUS,\s.*)\].*?\[.AREA\]
```

It is selecting the complete line. I understand why it is selecting the whole line, but can't figure out a way to ignore the first tag.

> **[AREA ROW, CHNO]Your card will be charged in Euros.[/AREA] [AREA UK,
>   US, HK]Discover,[/AREA]**

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is presence of greedy `.*` between `[AREA\s` and `,\sUS` in your regex which is matching longest match between `[AREA\s` and `,\sUS`.

You can use negated character class to allow it to match only until next comma:

```
\[AREA\s[^,]+,\sUS,\s.*?\].*?\[\/AREA\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/axELGw/3)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although i enjoy Regex, i don't do it often. Thank you for explaining the reason I was failing! I'm going to be using this logic for other  expressions now. very useful.